# Johnson-Neyman plot with 2-way interaction (pred = categorical, modx = continuous)

Tags: r, statistics, interaction

**Original post:** I am trying to create a Johnson-Neyman plot with a moderated regression where the predictor is a categorical IV with 2 groups, the moderator is a continuous variable, and the DV is a continuous variable.

I am using the "interactions" package on R with the johnson_neyman function.

This is my original model created (with actual variable names removed for ease):

```
moderation_mod <- lm(dv ~ iv*mod, data)
```

Here is what I'm doing to make the plot:

```
library("interactions")

johnson_neyman(model = moderation_mod, pred = iv, modx = mod)
```

Every time, I get this error:

> Error in vmat[pred, pred] : subscript out of bounds

I'm not sure what to do or what it means because it looks like it should work. TIA!

**Edit #1:** The data file is linked as a CSV [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HvvoEK2GoAtAqPOAYSqpQbABe-hy5jSu/view?usp=sharing)

The actual code I am using is:

```
# To make model: 
moderation_mod <- lm(abortion_attitude ~ condition*pol, empathy)

# Note: the condition variable is coded as low = 0, high = 1. 

# To create plot: 

library("interactions")

johnson_neyman(model = moderation_mod, pred = condition, modx = pol)

# The error: Error in vmat[pred, pred] : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: It doesn’t appear that you have provided enough information to debug this error.

Comment: @IRTFM just added more info.

Comment: It appears that the interactions package is not set up to handle plotting of a discrete predictor with a numeric modifier. You will probably need to do it the old-fashioned way by creating a prediction and then plotting separate lines for values of condition. Retraction my close vote because this is pretty straightforward with standard R functions in base and recommended packages.