# johnson_neyman () in R, gives Error "Error in vmat[pred, pred]:subscript out of bounds"

Tags: r, statistics, regression

My model looks like this:

"fear" (Score from 0 to 4 points) is dependent variable, age (Continuous variable) and group (Two groups: out_ group and in_group) are independent factors,.

The interaction of age * group was significant, so I wanted to see at what age point age appeared to have different effects on the two groups.

```
mod <- lm(fear~ 1 + age*group,  data = df)
johnson_neyman(mod, pred = group, modx = age, alpha = 0.05)
```

Error :"Error in vmat[pred, pred]:subscript out of bounds"

I have checked the data for a long time, but I still don't know where the mistake is.

Please help me see where the problem is and how I should modify it.
Thank you very much！

Comment: Do [the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76536695/johnson-neyman-plot-with-2-way-interaction-pred-categorical-modx-continuou) help ?